# php - not able te receive the email

Tags: php

**Below is the code**

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);

include('config.php');

// table name
$tbl_name="temp_members_db";

// Random confirmation code
$confirm_code=md5(uniqid(rand()));

// values sent from form
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$country=$_POST['country'];

// Insert data into database
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(confirm_code, name, email, password, country)VALUES('$confirm_code', '$name', '$email', '$password', '$country')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if suceesfully inserted data into database, send confirmation link to email
if($result){

// ---------------- SEND MAIL FORM ----------------

// send e-mail to ...
$to=$email;

// Your subject
$subject="Your confirmation link here";

// From
$header="from: your name <your email>";

// Your message
$message="Your Comfirmation link \r\n";
$message.="Click on this link to activate your account \r\n";
//$message.="http://www.yourweb.com/confirmation.php?passkey=$confirm_code";
$message.="http://localhost/confirmation.php?passkey=$confirm_code";

// send email   
$sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

}

// if not found
else {
echo "Not found your email in our database";
}

// if your email succesfully sent
if($sentmail){
echo "Your Confirmation link Has Been Sent To Your Email Address.";
}
else {
echo "Cannot send Confirmation link to your e-mail address";
}

?>
```

Comment: (-1) Please add a meaningful question and error description as well.

Comment: And, please, use the `code` function. Select your code and click the little _101010_ button in the editor.

Answer (score 1):

Some mailservers ( IE MailEnable ) aint handling the FROM correctly
a fix would be this

```
$header="FROM: your name <your email>";
```

To

```
$header="FROM: your email";
```

Answer (score 0):

whats the error you are getting and i think you try to send a email , if a mail server is not configured in local host you cant send emails

you can use a `SMTP` class to send mails using your SMTP mails like gmail

Comment: could you please help me with the command to install smtp server on ubuntu

Comment: You can use 'PHPMailer' Class http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/920.html , and send emails using a SMTP account like Gmail or any other .. i hope that u are expose to OOP programming in PHP

Comment: To install a SMTP server in ubuntu use the following command in Terminal

Comment: @Aos that should be asked on serverfault.com, not here

Comment: @Aos what the error description are u getting it will help to examine the problem !

Comment: @Sudantha...could u please help me with ur email id...so dat i can send u the detailed description...

Comment: @Aos asking users for one-on-one E-Mail support is rude. You can provide a detailed description by editing your question here, or opening a new one on serverfault.com